# facebook graph api webhook friend not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to keep track of my users' facebook friends. I thought that using the webhook is the best solution to this problem.

The webhook is currently working, the request I get from facebook is a json of 2 objects (users), who added each other as friends, so I am able to update them in the database.

For some reason I sometimes get an object of only one user, and I get the other friend in a seperate object. There is no way for me to relate the 2 requests together.

I have read through the whole document but it didn't help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5

Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is just using the webhooks for this task is not the right solution? If it's not the solution, should I scrape all my user's facebook friends periodically?

Comment: Had you found a solution?

Comment: yeah, i misunderstood the API, this is not how it should have been used, when i get a user object i need to query for their friends to see what changed myself

Comment: But to query friends you need the token, do you store token on server? what do you do if token will expire?

Comment: you restore the refresh token on the server, you use the refresh token to get a new access token when the access token expires